# How do display CommentForm in IndexView ? Django

Tags: python, django

I have comments for each post and I want that users can just type their comments and submit them on the same page 'IndexView'

here is my views.py

```
def IndexView(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        base_template_name = 'blog/base.html'
    else:
        base_template_name = 'blog/visitor.html'

    form = CommentForm()
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'form':form,'posts':posts,'base_template_name':base_template_name})


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            context = {'form':form}
            return render(request,'blog/index.html', context)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'form': form})
```

In `index.html` I put this (it displays the field put cannot submit it):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.textc }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is my `CommentForm` in `forms.py`

```
    class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ('textc',)
```

And `urls.py` for `index` and `comment`

```
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView, name = 'index'),
```

[Edit]: Here is my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    #slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True) 
    text = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()    

    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse('blog:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', null=True,related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    textc = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Thanks alot guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because inside the `IndexView` view (a good naming convention is use snake_case when its a function - `index_view` - and CamelCase when its a class - `IndexView`), you're not handling the `POST` data. Because you are not defining any `action` attribute inside the `<form>`, this form will be posted to the same url (same view).

Put this, inside the `IndexView` view:

```
def IndexView(request):
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        base_template_name = 'blog/base.html'
    else:
        base_template_name = 'blog/visitor.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # handle here the form.cleaned_data.get('textc')
            # and then redirect, if necessary
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'base_template_name': base_template_name})
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch a specific `post` object based on form data (`textrc`)? If so, then you're missing your `models.py` file from your question.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a github account yet :( any suggestion ?